# System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' C# MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to use this code to get the sum of amount from database:

```
MySqlCommand cmdsumpayment = new MySqlCommand("SELECT sum(amount) as'total' from payments where unit_id = " + UNITID + " AND deleted_at IS NULL", conn);
                        MySqlDataReader rdr2 = cmdsumpayment.ExecuteReader();
                        if (rdr2.HasRows) {
                            while (rdr2.Read())
                        {
                            TOTALPAYMENTS = rdr2.GetInt32("total");
                        }
                        }
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show("nothing found");
```

It works and I can get the sum(amount) from the payments table but my problem is if I search for something that does not have payments, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.
```

For example, if unit id = 1 and it does have payments, I can have the result in TOTALPAYMENTS but if it does not have any payments I get errors and the application crashed.
can someone help me with how to handle the empty search without crashing?
I also try `if (rdr2.HasRows)` but it does not work, I don't know why.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: You can use `ifnull(sum(amount), 0)` or you can explicitly check for `DBNull.Value`. You are also missing parameterization, `using` blocks and `if (rdr2.HasRows)` is unnecessary

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks for the advice, I am practicing right now with queries but I will look into it ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am 100% sure that you have `amount` null in the table and then you are getting type cast while converting to integer.
With the code you have posted you’ll not get the type cast exception if there are no rows in the table for the given condition. So you can put breakpoint and debug or put some logs. You can also try running the query directly into the database to see whether it’s returning records or not.

You can modify the query if amount is null.

```
SELECT ifnull(sum(amount), 0) as `total` from payments where unit_id = " + UNITID + " AND deleted_at IS NULL
```

And I would recommend to use parameterised query to avoid sql injection.

**Edit**: I have got the root cause of your issue. [SqlDataReader.GetInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) expects integer value and you are passing string value. So you need to pass `0` instead of `“total”`.  As mentioned in the documentation you should call [IsDBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to check for null values before calling this method

Comment: Hello, I have tried your code but I get this error: `MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull''` . Also, i just unchecked Allow Null for Amount column, so we are now sure there is no Null amount there, the problem is it will give an error when we are looking for something that does not exist, I mean `UNITID =1` exists but `UNITID = 10` does not exist there, that's when I got the error. sorry for my bad English.
check these to picture I think you will understand me:

Comment: [link](https://pasteboard.co/HWRJGlH0e5XC.jpg) and [link](https://pasteboard.co/PoB5SpDKdw5W.jpg

Comment: Which line is giving exception @ArsalanAhmadi ?

Comment: When i use `sum(amount) as 'total'` this line is giving me error: `TOTALPAYMENTS = rdr2.GetInt32("total");`  and the error is : `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.`
but when i use the query you send me, this line give me error: `MySqlDataReader rdr2 = cmdsumpayment.ExecuteReader();` and the error is : `MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull''`

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi check the **edit** section of my answer

Comment: thank you for the help, i fix the problem by adding `if (!rdr2.IsDBNull(rdr2.GetOrdinal("total")))` before `TOTALPAYMENTS = rdr2.GetInt32("total");` as you teach me.
and about the SQL injection, I'm a little new so I am trying to learn query and how to work with it for now, then I will try to learn how to avoid injections.